# How to increase log size in Google Container Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

We would like to increase the size of the logs that `kubectl log` retrieves.

As of [Container-Optimized OS (COS)](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/) VERSION_ID=56 BUILD_ID=9000.84.2 (according to `/etc/os-release`), the following logrotate script is used: /etc/logrotate.d/docker-containers:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log {
    rotate 5
    copytruncate
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    maxsize 10M
    daily
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s
    create 0644 root root
}
```

How can I increase the maxsize from 10M?

One thing I thought would be set the user-data metadata within the nodePools creation, but the [NodeConfig documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig) states that this is impossible: “keys must not conflict with any other metadata keys for the project or be one of the four reserved keys: "instance-template", "kube-env", "startup-script", and "user-data"”

Answer (score 1):

In Google Container Engine clusters that are created from newer build of [Container-Optimized OS (COS)](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) images the value of `maxsize` for logrotate is changed to `100M`

```
/var/log/*.log {
    rotate 5
    copytruncate
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    maxsize 100M
    daily
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s
    create 0644 root root
}
```